# bootstrap row-flexbox on Firefox doesn't break to a new line

Tags: html, css, less, flexbox

I have a layout using flex mode. It is fine in Chrome and Safari, however, in Firefox and IE it looks quite bad.
This is my html:

```
<div ng-repeat="section in categorySections" class="row-flex row-flex-wrap">
    <div class="flex-col lesson-section col-md-12">
        <h2>{{ section.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ section.description }}</p>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="lesson in section.lessons" class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel flex-col">
            <div class="panel-title">
                <h3>{{ lesson.title }}</h3>
                <small>{{ lesson.date }}</small>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body flex-grow">
                <p>{{ lesson.shortDescription }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <a href="#/chords/{{ lesson.id }}"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Continue</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.row-flex, .row-flex > div[class*='col-'] {  
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
flex:1 1 auto;
}

.row-flex-wrap {
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex:0;
}

.row-flex > div[class*='col-'], .container-flex > div[class*='col-'] {
     margin:-.2px; /* hack adjust for wrapping */
}

.container-flex > div[class*='col-'] div, .row-flex > div[class*='col-'] div {
    width:100%;
}

.flex-col {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex: 1 100%;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.flex-grow {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex: 2;
    flex: 2;
}
```

and this is how it looks in Firefox:
[image]

The cards should be under the title and not on the right side of the page.

Does anybody help me what I do wrong?

Comment: Hi! I don't have Firefox to test, but you could try adding `display: block`, `display: inline-block`, `width: 100%` and similar to the elements not behaving. Those are typical properties that are interpreted differently in IE and Chrome when working with Flex.

Comment: From my experience if there is a problem showing in Firefox and not Chrome, the problem is Chrome. Firefox hardly ever gives issues and Chome when when right, is wrong, and is probably a bug causing it to show correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
    display:-moz-deck;
    width:100%;
}
```